# Border distance between different columns

Tags: html, css

This is what i´m trying to achieve:
[image]

The problem I have is that on resize the blank space between the columns always change looking different on width and height from the others:

This is my markup:

```
<div id="wrapper">  
   <div id="header" class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="layout clearfix"> 
   <div class="small_box top_left ">
    <img class="fittobox" src="img/home7.jpg" alt="home7" width="800" height="689">
   </div>
   <div class="small_box top_middle large_h">
    <img class="fittobox" src="img/home6.jpg" alt="home6" width="747" height="1330">
   </div>
   <div class="small_box top_right">
    <img class="fittobox" src="img/home5.jpg" alt="home5" width="503" height="460">
   </div>
   <div class="small_box bottom_left">
     <img class="fittobox" src="img/home2.jpg" alt="home2" width="830" height="800">
   </div>
   <div class="small_box bottom_right">
     <img class="fittobox" src="img/home7.jpg" alt="home7" width="800" height="689">
   </div>               
   </div><!-- Layout -->        
 </div><!-- wrapper -->
```

With this LESS:

```
    /*---- HOME - SHOP - TIENDAS LAYOUT ----*/
    .layout{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        z-index: 1;
        overflow: hidden;
        min-height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        .fittobox{
            display: none;
        }
        .small_box{
            width: 33%;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 45%;
            position: absolute;
            &.top_left{
                top: 3%;
            }
            &.top_middle{
                top: 3%;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -16%;
            }
            &.top_right{
                top: 3%;
                right: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                width: 32%;
            }
            &.bottom_left{
                bottom: 40px;
                left: 0;
            }
            &.bottom_middle{
                bottom: 40px;
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -16%;
            }
            &.bottom_right{
                bottom: 40px;
                right: 0;
                margin-right: 0;
                width: 32%;
            }
            &.large_h{
                top: 3%;
                height: 93%;
            }
            &.fullscreen{
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
            &.halfscreen{
                width: 67%;
                height: 93%;
                top: 3%;
            }
    }
```

Comment: The problem comes from the fact that because your box heights and widths are percentages it also leaves your margins as percentages so they scale with the size of the window. No plain CSS way springs to mind off the top of my head sadly though you may get some results by making the percentages add up and then using pixel based padding inside the panels for your margins...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard box model places stuff like the borders, paddings and margins outside of the box.

This means that if you have a group of boxes with sizes in percentages that you want to add up to 100%, you can't have padding between them.

However you can change the box model so that the padding etc is inside the box, using CSS `box-sizing:border-box;`.

With this set, you can now specify your boxes so that they add up to 100%, but still give them padding and margin in pixels without messing up the layout.

Hope that helps.

Read more about `box-sizing` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/box-sizing

Browser compatibility: Not supported in IE6 or IE7. Works fine in all other browsers. (polyfills for IE6/7 [can be found here](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#basic-user-interface-spec)).